# aws lambda update-function-code: syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, aws-lambda, syntax-error

I'm trying to update a Lambda function using this command:

`aws lambda update-function-code --function-name my-function --zip-file fileb://package.zip`

However, this results in a Windows Script Host error:

```
/path/to/aws.js
Line: 1
Char: 1
Error: Syntax error
Code: 800A03EA
Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

The contents of `aws.js`:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  api_version: '2012-08-10',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

exports.iot = new AWS.IotData({
  apiVersion: '2015-05-28',
  endpoint: 'redacted.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

exports.AWS = AWS;
```

If I run this file using node (`node /path/to/aws.js`), I get no output. If I double-click on the file, I get the same error.

It seems like `aws lambda update-function-code` is checking the file for syntax errors, but not using node.

I don't see any node syntax errors. How can I solve this?

I'm using NVM for Windows (I'm on Windows 10), and node v10.23.0 is active. I have successfully updated this function before, and I made no changes to `aws.js`.

Comment: Many AWS commands like this can have problems running in Windows because of the slashes in the command. I suggest trying the same command in WSL2.

Comment: @derpirscher Same result. The docs say `fileb`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

Comment: @MarkB Thank you! Running the command in Git Bash solved the issue. I will accept if you post an answer.